# Investigating the features' importance and weights evolution in given DL model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, feature-selection

I apologize for a longer than usual intro, but it is important for the question:

I've recently been assigned to work on an existing project, which uses Keras+Tensorflow to create a Fully Connected Net.

Overall the model has 3 fully connected layers with 500 neurons and has 2 output classes. The first layer has 500 neurons which are connected to 82 input features. The model is used in the production and is retrained weekly, using this week information generated by an outer source.

The engineer which designed the model is no longer working here and I'm trying to reverse engineer and understand the behavior of the model.

Couple of objectives I have defined for myself are:

1. Understand the feature selection process and feature importance.
2. Understand and control the weekly re-training process.

In order to try and answer both of them, I've implemented an experiment where I feed my code with two models: one from the previous week and the other from the current week:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import model_from_json

path1 = 'C:/Model/20190114/'
path2 = 'C:/Model/20190107/'
model_name1 = '0_10.1'
model_name2 = '0_10.2'

models = [path1 + model_name1, path2 + model_name2]
features_cum_weight = {}
```

I then take each feature and try to sum all the weights (their absolute value) which connect it to the first hidden layer.
This way I create two vectors of 82 values:

```
for model_name in models:
    structure_filename = model_name + "_structure.json"
    weights_filename = model_name + "_weights.h5"

    with open(structure_filename, 'r') as model_json:
        model = model_from_json(model_json.read())
        model.load_weights(weights_filename)

    in_layer_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
    in_layer_weights = abs(in_layer_weights)
    features_cum_weight[model_name] = in_layer_weights.sum(axis=1)
```

I then plot them, using MatplotLib:

```
# Plot the Evolvement of Input Neuron Weights:
keys = list(features_cum_weight.keys())
weights_1 = features_cum_weight[keys[0]]
weights_2 = features_cum_weight[keys[1]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

n_plots = 4
batch = int(np.ceil(len(weights_1)/n_plots))

for i in range(n_plots):
    start = i*(batch+1)
    stop  = min(len(weights_1), start + batch + 1)
    cur_w1 = weights_1[start:stop]
    cur_w2 = weights_2[start:stop]

    ind = np.arange(len(cur_w1))
    cur_ax = ax[i//2][i%2]

    cur_ax.bar(ind - width/2, cur_w1, width, color='SkyBlue', label='Current Model')
    cur_ax.bar(ind + width/2, cur_w2, width, color='IndianRed', label='Previous Model')

    cur_ax.set_ylabel('Sum of Weights')
    cur_ax.set_title('Sum of all weights connected by feature')
    cur_ax.set_xticks(ind)
    cur_ax.legend()
    cur_ax.set_ylim(0, 30)

plt.show()
```

Resulting in the following plot:

[MatPlotLib plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqiJg.png)

I then try to compare the vectors to deduce:

1. If the vectors have been changed drastically - there might be some major change in the training data or some problem while retraining the model.
2. If some value is close to zero the model might have recognized this feature as not important.

I want your opinion and insights on the following:

1. The overall approach to this experiment.
2. Advice on other ideas on reverse engineering on a given model.
3. Insights on the output I provide here.

Thank you all, I am open to any suggestions and critic!

Comment: Have you got absolutely no access to the source code of the model?

Comment: I am quite sure Q1 and Q3 are not programming questions (thus off-topic), Q2 might be on-topic, but I don't really see the problem, you have the model in a JSON file, which you can open it to see layers, connections, etc, in a human-interpretable file.

Comment: @FilipeAleixo,
I do have access to the source code of the model training. It doesn't give me much information on feature importance or the way the weights are evolving in between the training sessions. I can, of course, see the architecture and have access to the training loss, etc.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro,
As I replied in a previous comment I do have the architecture, but I want to create some process to interpret the weights evolution from session to session, specifically in connection to features importance...
I accept your comment on irrelevance of some of the questions, do you think there is another "community" where these questions would be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, most likely http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of deduction is not entirely true. The combination between the features is not linear. It is true that if is strictly 0 does not matter, but it may be that it is then recombined in another way and in another deep layer.

It would be true if your model is linear. In fact, this is how the PCA analysis works, where it searches for linear relationships through the covariance matrix. The eigenvalue would indicate the importance of each feature.

I think that there are several ways to confirm your suspicions:

1. Eliminate features that you think are not important to train again and see the result. If it is similar, your suspicions are correct.
2. Apply the current model, take an example (we will call it as pivot) to evaluate and significantly change the features that you consider irrelevant and create many examples. This applies for several pivots. If the result is similar, that field should not matter. Example (I consider the first feature to be irrelevant):

   ```py
   data = np.array([[0.5, 1, 0.5], [1, 2, 5]])
   range_values = 50

   new_data = []
   for i in range(data.shape[0]):
       sample = data[i]
       # We create new samples 
       for i in range (1000):
           noise = np.random.rand () * range_values
           new_sample = sample.copy()
           new_sample[0] += noise
           new_data.append(new_sample)
   ```

Comment: Thank you Adria for your inputs, you are right about the fact that in deeper layers the features are combined non-linearly, I am working currently on the second approach you proposed, trying to create randomized features and then testing the resulting predictions.